# How do I create a histogram of the samples with a delta of 0.01 in MATLab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, histogram, gaussian, delta

I created an array of 1,000,000 samples of a uniform random variable on the interval
(0,1). And then created a histogram  where the values are the random numbers that were generated. I don't quite understand using the delta of 0.01 to create the histogram.

```
rng('default')
array=rand(1000000,1);
[x,y]=hist(array,100)
```

Comment: `hist` is deprecated. Better use [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html).  The syntax `histogram(...,'BinWidth',BW)`, or `histogram(...,'BinLimits',[...])`, is probably what you want

Answer (score 2):

You can use `histogram` directly to produce a plot

```
% Histogram binning and plot
edges = 0:0.01:1;
histogram( array, edges );
```

Or you can use `histcounts` to get the bin data, and then plot easily with `bar` if desired.

```
% Histogram binning
edges = 0:0.01:1;
hc = histcounts( array, edges );
% Plot
centres = (edges(1:end-1)+edges(2:end))/2;
bar( centres, hc );
```

In both cases, I'm specifying the bin size as `0.01` in the definition of `edges`.